# Instantiating object in class to access variables vs passing object variables to constructor

Tags: java, oop

Say for example I have two classes A and B.
If B needs to access some variables in class A, would it be better to :

1. Instantiate an object of class A within class B to access the variables or,
2. When I instantiate the two objects in my main method, pass the variables from object A to the object B to the constructor arguments.

At the moment, I am leaning towards option 2 as in option 1, we will have to instantiate two objects of class A (one in main method, one in class B) whereas in option 2, we only have to instantiate one object of class A in the main method and pass the variables over.

I sought clarification for the most common or object oriented way to implement this.

Thanks

Comment: Could B be a subclass of A instead? i.e. `class B extends A`

Comment: The answer to this really depends very much on what kind of data `A` is sharing with `B`. Is `B` the only class which needs the data from `A`? Or, more strongly, does `A` only exist to interact with `B`? It might be helpful to know a little bit more about the context of your code. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think there is any answer that works for all `A` and `B`.  It's a common mistake to want some rule that you can follow without thinking, but I believe this is harmful.  The goal of "object-oriented programming" is to make code easier to read, maintain, and test.  But it requires some understanding of _why_ OO features achieve those goals.  If you try to follow a rule or pattern without understanding, the result is too likely to code that achieves the opposite.  I may be going against the trend of trusting in "patterns", but my long experience tells me this is true.